# Invalid Memory Acess for JavaFX ScrollBar on Snow-Leopard

Tags: user-interface, javafx, osx-snow-leopard, javafx-1

I created the following JavaFX script, which when run, generates an Invalid memory access on Snow-Leopard. What is it about javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar that is causing a memory failure?

```
Stage {
    title: "Scroll View"
    scene: Scene {
        content: [
            ScrollBar {
                min: 0
                max: 100
                value: 0
                blockIncrement: 10
                vertical: false
            }
        ]
    }
    resizable: false
}
```

I'm using whatever JavaFX (at least 1.2) that comes with NetBeans 6.8:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610)
Java: 1.6.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.3-b01-101
System: Mac OS X version 10.6.2 running on x86_64; MacRoman; en_US (nb)
```

Comment: I also installed the 1.2.3 JavaFX SDK and created a new JavaFX platform for NetBeans to use. It also gives me the memory access error.

Comment: I also saw a post regarding 64bit v 32bit execution. I used `arch -i386 javafx ...` to launch the class and still fails with the same error.

Comment: Seems also to happen when using the Slider component.

Comment: I confirmed this morning that this bug is ONLY with OS X. Whether it's only with Snow-Leopard, I can't say. Can anyone out there test on alternate OS X distros (leopard, tiger, jaguar)?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your example using 
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610)
Java: 1.6.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.3-b01-101
System: Mac OS X version 10.6.2 running on x86_64; MacRoman; en_US (nb)
javafx 1.2.3_b36

With no error.

Comment: How did you get the javafx version number? I know I'm using 1.2.3, not sure if it's build 36 or earlier.